# How to set up Watson ConversationService in F#

Tags: f#, watson-conversation, c#-to-f#

Initializing the ConversationService() object in C# if fairly straightforward, but I'm having issues doing the same in F#. When I run the code below, I get a `Parameter name: versionDate cannot be null. Use 'CONVERSATION_VERSION_DATE_2017_05_26'` error.

I've tried manually adding `"versionDate": "2017-05-26"` and `"version_date": "2017-05-26"`  to the `credential` string, but it is still producing the same error.

Is there a way I can pass the version date correctly to the ConversationService object to avoid this null pointer exception?

**C# Version**

```
ConversationService service = new ConversationService( <username> , <password> , ConversationService.CONVERSATION_VERSION_DATE_2017_05_26);
```

**F# Version**

```
let credential = """
                    {
                      "url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api",
                      "username": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                      "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    }
                 """              

let workspaceID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
let service = new ConversationService()                                                
service.SetCredential credential
```

Comment: Well, why aren't you using constructor arguments like you do in C#? Since you're not specifying the third argument, it's no surprise that the library complains about it missing.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Well I feel like a complete idiot. I relied too heavily on intellisense and gave up when I didn't see an autocompletion. Thanks a lot!